# Link error in Borland 6.0

Tags: linker, c++builder, c++builder-6

Got Link error (Fatal: Access violation. Link terminated) in Borland 6.0.

How do I know what is the cause of it ?

Is there any output file that I can open and get more informative message ?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the command line that gets passed to the linker to determine which .obj files are being passed to the linker. You can then include/exclude files to see when the error occurs.

A number of linker problems have been fixed since BCB6, you may want to try the linker from a demo of a newer version to see if that solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Some files in the project had incorrect file path.