# Link error in Borland

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-6

Got Link error (Fatal: Access violation. Link terminated) in Borland C++Builder 6.0.

How do I know what is the cause of it ?

Is there any output file that I can open and get more informative message ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Borland 6.0 what? What were you doing when you got the error? Were you programming or should you be asking this as an application question on Superuser?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184763/got-link-error-fatal-access-violation-link-terminated-in-borland-6-0

Perhaps add more info the next time around instead of an exact copy and paste. It may help you get an answer.

Comment: Borland WHAT? This is like saying there is an error in Microsoft 2007.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Link error in Borland 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184763/link-error-in-borland-6-0)

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes, for no reason, I get these messages too. When this happen, I have to restart BCB6 to get things done.
There are updates related to this problem you can try from [Embarcadero site](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/29793).

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the command line that gets passed to the linker to determine which .obj files are being passed to the linker. You can then include/exclude files to see when the error occurs.

A number of linker problems have been fixed since BCB6, you may want to try the linker from a demo of a newer version to see if that solves your problem.